# Is Terracotta a kind of reliable alternative to JVMs?

Tags: jvm, terracotta

I come across Terracotta as a distributed JVM that is stable and robust, however as my understanding of Terracotta is shallow, i am not sure if Terracotta is an alternative to JVMs?

It looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terracotta is not a JVM, it's a shared memory backplane.  It does not replace the JVM in any way.  Terracotta now owns and makes several projects which can leverage this backplane.

They include

- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)
- [Sessions](http://www.terracotta.org/products/web-sessions)
- [Quartz](http://www.terracotta.org/products/quartz-scheduler)

Amongst others. Their product BigMemory also helps to overcome some of the JVM Heap issues with very large allocations.